# Jquery: Traversing li and get element within

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, traversal

This question seems easy but I just can't get it right.

```
<ul id="myUL">
   <li id="item1">
      <select class="partDesc"><option>Front</option><option>Rear</option></select>
      <input type="text" class="itemDesc">
      <img src="images/myimg.jpg" class="itemImg" > 
   </li>
   <li id="item2">
      <select class="partDesc"><option>Front</option><option>Rear</option></select>
      <input type="text" class="itemDesc">
      <img src="images/myimg.jpg" class="itemImg" > 
   </li>
</ul>
```

These `<li>` items are dynamically added using jquery.
I want to traverse these `<li>` items and get all the inputs, including selected value from `partDesc`, text from `itemDes` and `src` from `itemImg`.

Here is where I stuck:

```
$("#myUL li").each(function() {<br>
    var partDesc = $(this).??;<br>
    var itemDesc = $(this).??;<br>
    var itemImg = $(this).??;<br>
 });
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

following script should help you. here is the [`demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/txxmh/)

```
$("#myUL li").each(function() {
    var partDesc = $(this).find('.partDesc').val();
    var itemDesc = $(this).find('.itemDesc').val();
    var itemImg = $(this).find('.itemImg').attr('src');
    alert('partDesc: '+partDesc);
    alert('itemDesc: '+itemDesc );
    alert('itemImg: '+itemImg );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myUL li").each(function() {
    var partDesc = $(this).children("select:selected").text();
    var itemDesc = $(this).children("input").val();
    var itemImg = $(this).children("img").attr("src");
});
```